# How to still use expo go for development when you have a non supported module

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go

I use expo go and simulator locally to do development.  It is very handy to be able to refresh and such without doing a whole new build when I am developing - especially ui stuff.  However, I recently started trying to implement push notifications to my app.  I do understand that the modules required are not compatible with expo go. However, by adding them I can no longer develop and test other things since these modules break the expo go simulator.  How can I somehow ignore modules that are not compatible for development of other features that are compatible?